# Partial derivative is bounded

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, self-learning

Let $f(t,z)$ be a bounded (say by a constant $M$) continuous function on $\mathbb{R}_t \times \mathcal{U}$ where $\mathcal{U}$ is an open neighborhood of $0 \in \mathbb{C}_z$. Moreover, for each fixed $t \in \mathbb{R}_t$, assume that $f$ is analytic in $\mathcal{U}$.

**Questions**

1. Is $\partial f /\partial z$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}_t \times \mathcal{U}$? How do I show this?
2. For $r > 0$, let $D_r(a)$ be a closed disk of radius $r$, centered at $a$. Is there an $r > 0$ for which $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} (t,z)$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}_t \times D_r(0)$?

**My Attempt:** Fix an acceptable $r >0$ so that $D_r(0) \subset \mathcal{U}$. Let $0 < r' < r$. Then $D_{r'}(0) \subset D_r(0)$. If we take an $a \in D_{r'}(0)$, then $D_{r-r'}(a) \subset D_r(0)$. We can use Cauchy's estimate to get
$$ \left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} (t,a) \right| \leq \frac{M}{r-r'} \text{ on } \mathbb{R}_t. $$
Since $a$ is arbitrary, we have 
$$ \left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} (t,z) \right| \leq \frac{M}{r-r'} \text{ on } \mathbb{R}_t \times D_{r'}(0). $$

Am I on the right track here? Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It doesn't matter for the answer (why?), but by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, do you mean the partial derivative with respect to the real part of the complex argument, or do you - as later notation suggests - denote the complex argument by $x$ and mean the Wirtinger derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ as opposed to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{x}}$? As for the answers to your question, what you wrote is good for question 2, for question 1, instead of going for the Cauchy estimate, you should have taken another turn from the integral formula.

Comment: Oops, that's a typo. All the $x$'s should be $z$'s instead... correcting it now.

Comment: Ok, so is my answer for (2) already complete provided I can show (1)?

Comment: It's not quite correct, if you have a bound on $\partial f/\partial z(t,0)$, then usually you can't have the same bound for $\partial f/\partial z(t,z),\; z\in D_{r'}(0)$. You need a larger bound. But the Cauchy estimates give you a bound on $\mathbb{R}\times D_{r'}(0)$ for every $r' < r$. If you use the correct bound, question 2 will be correctly answered.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about getting an estimate on $\mathbb{R} \times D_{r'}$ for all $r' < r$. But I realize that I cannot use the same bound (because of the possibility of equality). Then will it work if I use something like $(M/r) + 1$? Or am I missing your point here?

Comment: If you use $M' = (M/r)+1$, then you don't know on how large a disk that bound holds for a fixed $t$. Say $\lvert \partial f/\partial z(t,z)\rvert \leqslant M'$ on $\{t\}\times D_{\rho(t)}(0)$. Then how do you know/show that $\inf \{ \rho(t) : t\in\mathbb{R}\} > 0$?. The Cauchy estimates give you, for every $r' < r$ a bound $M'(r')$ such that $\lvert\partial f/\partial z(t,z)\rvert \leqslant M'(r')$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $z\in D_{r'}(0)$.

Comment: I see, I understand what you mean. I was afraid I was missing something like that. I've edited my attempt so I'll appreciate it if you can check it again. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Now, how do we use the integral formula to show continuity?

Comment: Still stumped with that one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answer question 2 correctly, the Cauchy estimates show that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ is uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{R}\times D_r(0)$ for all $r > 0$ such that $\overline{D_r(0)} \subset \mathcal{U}$.

To see the continuity of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$, fix a $z_0\in\mathcal{U}$. Then for $r > 0$ small enough that $\overline{D_r(z_0)} \subset \mathcal{U}$, the Cauchy integral formula for the derivative gives you

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(t,z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert \zeta-z_0\rvert = r} \frac{f(t,\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^2}\,d\zeta\tag{1}$$

for all $(t,z) \in \mathbb{R}\times D_r(z_0)$. The integrand

$$h(t,z,\zeta) = \frac{f(t,\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^2}$$

is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\times D_r(z_0)$ (and uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{R}\times D_\rho(z_0)$ for all $\rho \in (0,r)$), so the integral $(1)$ is continuous. The exact argument for the continuity depends on whether you consider the integral as a Lebesgue integral, a Riemann integral, or some other type of integral. For the Lebesgue integral, the usual argument would be the dominated convergence theorem, for the Riemann integral, one would probably argue with the uniform continuity of continuous functions on compact spaces, which means that the integrands in

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} (t_n,z_n) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert\zeta - z_0\rvert = r} \frac{f(t_n,\zeta)}{(\zeta - z_n)^2}\,d\zeta$$

converge uniformly to $\frac{f(t,z)}{(\zeta-z)^2}$ on the circle $\lvert \zeta-z_0\rvert = r$ as $(t_n,z_n) \to (t,z)$.